# Google Workplace API OAuth2 token is obtained successfully in the local environment, but it doesn't work in the production environment

Tags: go, google-workspace

I am trying to get consent from user to modify there gmail and calendar from google api And code works fin in local but it does not work in production And I am not able to figure out whats the issue also it does not return any error

```
func setGoogleApiRoutes(router *gin.RouterGroup) {
    googleApiGrp := router.Group("/google-api")
    googleApiGrp.GET("/consent", authMiddleware(getTokenGoogleApi))
    googleApiGrp.GET("/callback", WithoutAuthMiddleware(handleGoogleCallback))
    googleApiGrp.POST("/send-email", authMiddleware(sendEmail))
    googleApiGrp.DELETE("/delete-email", authMiddleware(deleteEmail))
    googleApiGrp.GET("/get-emails-by-thread", authMiddleware(getEmailsByThread))
    googleApiGrp.GET("/emails", authMiddleware(getEmailList))
}

func getTokenGoogleApi(c *context.Context) {
    gService := googleworkplaceapi.New()
    url := gService.GetConsentUrl()
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"url": url})
}

func handleGoogleCallback(c *context.Context) {
    cfg := config.Get()
    params := c.Request.URL.Query().Get("code")
    if params == "" {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Code not found"})
        return
    }
    gService := googleworkplaceapi.New()
    token, err := gService.GetToken(c, params)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Failed to exchange code for token"})
        return
    }

    redirectURL := fmt.Sprintf("%v/google-auth?token=%v", cfg.FeBaseURL, token.RefreshToken)
    fmt.Println(token.RefreshToken, "token")
    fmt.Println(redirectURL, "redirectURL")
    c.Redirect(http.StatusPermanentRedirect, redirectURL)
}

func New() *GoogleWorkplaceApi {
    cfg := config.Get()
    return &GoogleWorkplaceApi{
        GoogleClientID:      cfg.GoogleClientID,
        GoogleClientSecrete: cfg.GoogleClientSecret,
        BaseUrl:             cfg.BaseURL,
    }
}

func (g *GoogleWorkplaceApi) GetConsentUrl() string {
    var gConfig = &oauth2.Config{}
    gConfig.ClientID = g.GoogleClientID
    gConfig.ClientSecret = g.GoogleClientSecrete
    gConfig.Endpoint = google.Endpoint
    fmt.Println("g.BaseUrl", g.BaseUrl)
    gConfig.Scopes = []string{gmail.GmailModifyScope, calendar.CalendarScope}
    gConfig.RedirectURL = g.BaseUrl + "/google-api/callback" // if you want to change this uri needs to be added to google cloud
    url := gConfig.AuthCodeURL("state-token", oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
    fmt.Println(url)
    return url
}

func (g *GoogleWorkplaceApi) GetToken(ctx *context.Context, oAuth2Token string) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
    var gConfig = &oauth2.Config{}
    gConfig.ClientID = g.GoogleClientID
    gConfig.ClientSecret = g.GoogleClientSecrete
    gConfig.Endpoint = google.Endpoint
    gConfig.RedirectURL = g.BaseUrl + "/google-api/callback"
    gConfig.Scopes = []string{gmail.GmailModifyScope, calendar.CalendarScope}
    token, err := gConfig.Exchange(goDefault.TODO(), oAuth2Token, oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        ctx.Log.Error("Error while exchanging token", zap.Error(err))
        return nil, err
    }
    return token, nil
}
```

InFormation from my env variables are coming redirect URI is correct but when I am printing refresh token it is coming as empty string.
I suspect issue is with redirect URI because it is only variabel here but I have checked and made sure it is same as which is added in credential